# What is the equivalent of Android's Html.fromHtml() in WP7?

Tags: android, html, windows-phone-7, textblock

Is there a quick and dirty way to render HTML in a textblock in a fashion similar to Android's `Html.fromHtml()`? I am aware of how to manually parse it with something like the HtmlAgilityPack, but all I really want is for it to render like its source in the textblock.

If not naively then perhaps with a custom control of some sort and, no I don't want to render it as a web page.

Comment: Is there something from TextBlock you need and can't get using Browser Control? 
I am sure you have thought about it but adding it anyway. Not as a web page but, you can include a browser control in your page and parse HTML string into it.
    browserCtrl.NavigateToString("<html><body>HTML Text</body></html>");

Comment: @Claus there is one now. Smashed together a quick and dirty solution tweeking HtmlAgility and HtmlTextblock. see here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx) I'll upload to github tonight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok sorry it took so long. I all but forgot how to use git correctly and hadn't had the time to upload till now. This HtmlTextBlock offers a similar level of functionality as to that of its silverlight counterpart which is pretty close to the android equivalent. Its still a bit buggy at times when dealing with more complex tags like the html dtd tag but does the job....
 [WP7 Html Text Block](https://github.com/musicm122/WP7HtmlTextBlock-). The design is largely based on this guy's [Bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx). and rewriting the web browser related classes using html agility. One day I'll post the details but, blah... Not right now. lol

***Update***

Example of usage:

```
<local:HtmlTextBlock x:Name="htmlTextBlock" Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" UseDomAsParser="true" Text="<p>Your Html here </p>" />
```

Note: Your html will have to be escaped such that &lt = < and &gt = >

For detailed usage see:

https://github.com/musicm122/WP7HtmlTextBlock-/blob/master/HtmlTextBlockTest/HtmlTextBlockTest/MainPage.xaml

Comment: Glad you took the time, and did the the initial effort.

Comment: It was pretty fun. I enjoyed it.

Comment: Hi @Terrance.. Can you provide any sample or example for Html.fromHtml() in WP7?? Please..

Comment: @Vijay It doesn't work 1:1 that way with the control. 
You could update the Text property with the html you want to use and get pretty close to what you want. I update the answer and the docs to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: @Terrance.. Thanks.. It is working.. But, it will not support images ah?? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065062/equivalent-to-html-fromhtml-in-windows-phone-7/28081210#28081210) is my question. Can i use this control for this requirement??