# Equivalent to Html.fromHtml() in Windows phone 7

Tags: html, windows-phone-7

Hi I want to show html contents in display. When I try with web browser it showing the content. But we want to show the contents in TextBlock like android. We using HTML.fromHtml() to show the html contents in TextView. Please help me to find the alternative for HTML.fromHtml() in windows phone 7.

We try with web browser:

```
private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String htmlTags = "<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width='480', initial-scale='1'\"></head><body><center>{0}</center></body></html>";
            myWebView.NavigateToString(String.Format(htmlTags, getHTMLContent());
        }


 public string getHTMLContent()
        {
            StringBuilder htmlBody = new StringBuilder();
            htmlBody.Append("<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"704\" height=\"484\" background=\"https://known.com/img/back/123456.jpg\" style=\"background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;\">");
            htmlBody.Append("<tr>");
            htmlBody.Append("<td valign=top>");
            htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute;\">");
            htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 132px; height: 132px; top: 44px; left: 44px; z-index:0;\">");
            htmlBody.Append("<img src=\"https://known.com/img/icon/87654.jpg\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/>");
            htmlBody.Append("</div>");
            htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 704px; height: 484px; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index:0; \">");
            htmlBody.Append("<img src=\"https://known.com/img/icon/234255.jpg\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/>");
            htmlBody.Append("</div>");
            htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 440px; height: 264px; top: 184px; left: 184px; z-index:0;  font-family:times;  font-size:14px;  color:#FFFFFF; \" align=\"center\">");
            htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;\">");
            htmlBody.Append("</div>");
            htmlBody.Append("</div>");
            htmlBody.Append("</div>");
            htmlBody.Append("</td>");
            htmlBody.Append("</tr>");
            htmlBody.Append("</table>");
            return htmlBody.ToString();
        }
```

But we can not use this in our project due to client requirements. Please help us to find the alternative for HTML.fromHtml() in windows phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

In WP, nobody needs to see HTML code, at least, no-technical users, so, you must create and extension method for the RichTextBox Control [Text formatting in TextBlock Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485938/text-formatting-in-textblock-windows-phone-8-1) or you can use this http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/panels_labels_label_text_format.shtml